# How to create a custom symbol list item in Textmate?

Tags: javascript, html, textmate, textmatebundles

I am looking to create a custom "Symbol" for the "Symbol List" in Textmate so that I can have named bookmarks and jump to sections more easily.

Specifically I am trying to duplicate (from the CSS bundle)

```
/** something **/
```

That basically adds to Symbol List  * something *
I would like this in HTML and JavaScript as well. But can't figure out how to make it work.

Hope someone out there can help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `/** … **/` syntax in the language grammar first, and then use a Symbol List to add it to the menu. If you look at the CSS bundle, the "Symbol List: Group" preference looks for `source.css comment.block.css -source.css.embedded` scopes (i.e. comment blocks in CSS source, but not embedded comment blocks). The "comment.block.css" scope is defined in the CSS grammar.

To make your own for js or html, you'll need to edit the language grammar to look for the kinds of markers/comments you'd like to use, and then add a symbol list preference similar to the one in the CSS bundle (the one in the CSS bundle is basically doing a lot of substitution to make the name in the symbol list dropdown look pretty)

If you've never done anything like this before, it's rather complicated to explain. At least, to complicated to put in an answer here. But go to the ##textmate channel on Freenode and ask there, if you have further questions. Nice people, and a great resource for learning more about TextMate's innards: irc://irc.freenode.net/#%23textmate